# Spark (Pyspark) - Long delay between jobs

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have a spark job that performs some data analysis and there is a very long time between each job starting (1-2 hours). I know that some work isn't parallelized and doesn't count as a job so doesn't show up in the resource manager UI. I was hoping to find out what is taking so long? Here is my function:

```
def analyse(df, columns):
    return reduce(
        lambda a, b: a.union(b),
        (
            df.agg(
                F.count(F.when(F.isnull(c), c)).alias('NULL Count'),
                F.countDistinct(df[c]).alias('Distinct Values')
            ).select(F.lit(c).alias("Column Name"), "NULL Count", 'Distinct Values')
            for c in columns
        )
    )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "there is a very long time between each job starting"? there is a huge delay between your stages or for your whole job to be started?

Comment: huge delay before a job starts

Comment: what is the number of tasks in your job? a huge number of tasks may result in such a thing.